# jenkinsfile - How do I access custom properties in my pom.xml?

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, pom.xml

Let's say I have a custom property in my pom.xml set like this:

```
<properties>
 <app>com.myProject.app</app>
</properties>
```

How can I access it in my jenkinsfile?

This:

```
def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
def appName = pom.app
```

returns

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified field org.apache.maven.model.Model app
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `def appName = pom.project.properties.app`?

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work (I think).

Answer (score 8):

I know two approaches:

1. Use `properties-maven-plugin` to write the properties to a file. Use `readProperties` in the Jenkinsfile to read the properties.
   Works only if properties aren't needed until after Maven ran.
   Also, with the right circumstances, the properties file may be the stale one from a previous run, which is insiduous because the property values will be right anyway 99.9% of the time.
2. Use `pom = readMavenPom 'path/to/pom.xml'`. Afterwards, access the property like this: `pom.properties['com.myProject.app']`.

I like approach 2 much better: No extra plugin configuration in the POM, no file written, less sequencing constraints, less fragilities.

Comment: and what about custom property in profile ?

Comment: @hudi This question and answer are about how properties are accessed, you're asking what properties are there - that's a different question you should ask. (Basically, profiles are just normal Maven configuration to be added if it's active, but there are ramifications.) ... Except if you're asking about how to access the properties of an _inactive_ profile; this might be doable, but I never looked at the exact access path, and you probably should not be doing that because neither tools nor coworkers will understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 5):

In pipeline style, inside Jenkinsfile you can access the value as follows

```
pipeline {

environment {
      POM_APP = readMavenPom().getProperties().getProperty('app')
}

stages{
    stage('app stage'){
        steps{
            script{
                 sh """
                 echo ${POM_APP}
                 """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Read a maven project file](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readmavenpom-read-a-maven-project-file)

Answer (score 1):

jenkins pipeline add this stage.
more [see](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readmavenpom-read-a-maven-project-file)

```
    stage('info')
    {
        steps
        {
            script
            {
                def version = sh script: 'mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout', returnStdout: true
                def artifactId = sh script: 'mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.artifactId -q -DforceStdout', returnStdout: true
                
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this:
IMAGE = readMavenPom().getArtifactId()
VERSION = readMavenPom().getVersion()